# How to handle StackOverflowError

Tags: java, exception

What are the reasons for StackOverflowError Exception and whether it is checked or unchecked exception?

Comment: Check the elements that you are sending to stack. If You are passing more number of elements to stack, you might get this error.!

Comment: `StackOverflowError` extends `Error`. Hence, it is not required to catch it. It often happens when entering an infinite loop of recursive method calls.

Answer (score 3):

**A `StackOverflowError` is an `Error`**. Is **not an `Exception`**, so is not a checked or unchecked Exception.

The class hierarchy is the following:

```
                  Throwable
                      |
       +--------------+----------------+
       |                               |
     Error                         Exception 
       |                               |
       |                       +-------+----------------+
       |                       |                        |
StackOverFlowError       RuntimeException         SQLException
                               |
                               |
                      NullPointerException
```

Errors extends `Error`.

Checked exceptions extends `Exception`

Unchecked exceptions extends `RuntimeException`

---

This error happens when your **stack has too deep calls of methods**.

For example if you don't remember to define an exit strategy from a recursive function you can have a `StackOverflowError`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a glance at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html 

to have further information on this error.

Also, a piece of your code could help understand why this error happened.